# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](http://money.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Does there exist a kind of loan where no part of principal is paid, while interest is still paid?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23125/does-there-exist-a-kind-of-loan-where-no-part-of-principal-is-paid-while-intere)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Is writing out the entire spelling of the cents on a check acceptable?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23073/is-writing-out-the-entire-spelling-of-the-cents-on-a-check-acceptable)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why do 10 year Treasury bond yields affect mortgage interest rates?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/why-do-10-year-treasury-bond-yields-affect-mortgage-interest-rates)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Claiming Allowances on W4](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23195/claiming-allowances-on-w4)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Do the proceeds from selling an option immediately convert to buying power in a margin account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/do-the-proceeds-from-selling-an-option-immediately-convert-to-buying-power-in-a)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Temporarily reduce 401k contributions to help save for a downpayment?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23431/temporarily-reduce-401k-contributions-to-help-save-for-a-downpayment)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What do I use for the article number and % rate on the W-8BEN form, for publishing & selling my ebooks?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/what-do-i-use-for-the-article-number-and-rate-on-the-w-8ben-form-for-publishi)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What to enter on the check ordering form?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23257/what-to-enter-on-the-check-ordering-form)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What is the difference between a Loan, a Lien, and a Mortgage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23306/what-is-the-difference-between-a-loan-a-lien-and-a-mortgage)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why would a person not want to purchase a Personal Liability (Umbrella) insurance policy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23362/why-would-a-person-not-want-to-purchase-a-personal-liability-umbrella-insuranc)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)